# How will adding permissions to Microsoft Graph App effect existing users?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a registered App which requires several application permissions (getting them through Admin Consent flow).

The app is multi-tenant and is already serving a lot of users.

Now I would like to add some more permissions to what the App is requesting and I just want to make sure that adding these permissions won't effect my current users that are using the app.

I understand that in order for the new permissions to apply on existing users, their corresponding organizations admins will have to re-consent, but other than that, I would like to make sure (cant find it in docs) that current users will still be able to use the app the same way as they did before (without the features that requires the new permissions).

Is that really the case? nothing won't 'stop working' because of the permissions change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add permissions to an app registration, previous consents do not get revoked. however depending on the scopes that your app requests, it may force a new consent window to appear. since you are using application permissions, regular users cannot consent to the permissions. for example if your client is requesting a .default scope, then it will try to get all the permissions specified in the api permissions, which would include the new permission (that needs consent). if your token requests only include the old permissions in the scope, then nothing should change.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#example-3-the-user-has-consented-and-the-client-requests-additional-scopes

But, I don't believe that the application will fail even if consent hasn't been given to the new application permissions, but it will fail to receive the new scopes if requested. and any resulting function that uses those additional permissions will fail, until an admin consents to those new permissions.